# See entire POST request from Android app

Tags: android, wcf, post, httprequest, http-post

I'm trying to debug a little problem I have with a web service. I cannot POST to the webservice, but I can GET just fine.

When I try to post data to the webservice I get a HTTP 1/1 400 Bad Request.

Is there a way I can see more details?.. I dont have access to the server, on which the webservice is hosted

HTTP Post code

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://lino.herter.dk/Service.svc/Data/");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

StringEntity se = new StringEntity("test");
se.setContentType("text/xml");
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
httppost.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httppost);
sb = inputStreamToString(response2.getEntity().getContent());
```

Comment: Could you paste the code responsible for making POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to set up Wireshark on your development machine, and capture the traffic between your Android and the server. You'll have to run Wireshark in Promiscuous mode, which I think is the default option.

Comment: OMG...you set promiscuous mode you would see a load of stupid junk, I dont even think he has chance to find what he is even doing :)

Comment: You use capture filters to filter out all the junk you don't want. Promiscuous mode is the only way to capture traffic between two external devices.

Comment: Just installed it and it worked just fine.. :) I saw exactly what was wrong with my request.. :)